# remove index & headers from dataframe while styling

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an xlsx & creating a html while applying some style using jinja2

```
import pandas
import jinja2

df = pandas.read_excel('C:\\Users...\\2020.xlsx', 'TEST',
                       usecols = 'A:J')
pandas.set_option('precision', 2)

df_dropna = df.dropna(how = 'all')
df_fillna = df_dropna.fillna('')

#html = df_fillna.to_html(index=0,header=False,border=0)

def highlight(val):
    if (val in ('USERID','Name')) :
        return 'background-color: yellow'
    else:
        return 'background-color: white'

styler = (df_fillna.style.applymap(highlight))

# Template handling
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=''))
template = env.get_template('template2.html')
outputText = template.render(my_table=styler.render())

html_file = open('trial.html', 'w')
html_file.write(outputText)
html_file.close()
```

Code works perfectly fine, except that I am not able to get rid of header & index. Anything that can help remove index & header? Please help!
 See below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution was not in Pyhton code, but I had to put it in my template for css

below is the code to hide index & header

```
table td.first { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling render method overrid head parameter with empty list.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html

Something like:

```
render(head=[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the style.css in the Table settings worked for me.

```css
th:nth-of-type(1){ display: none; }
```

```css
   table         { margin-bottom: 0em; width:100%;}
   th            { font-weight: bold; text-align: center;}
   thead th      { background: #c3d9ff; }
   th:nth-of-type(1){ display: none; }
   th,td,caption { padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px; }
```